# Upload file in remote server for Android

Tags: android

i followed this tutorial but instead of getting 200 i get always 302 for server response.

[turorial](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/upload-file-to-remote-server-in-android.html)

Can anybody check on this?

Answer (score 0):

i used this code in my app. its worked. it may help you.

```
private String doFileUpload() {

    final DataOutputStream dos;

    String exiting_file_path = filePath;
    String boundary = "*****";
    String twohypens = "--";
    String lineend = "\r\n";
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    int buferSize;
    int bytesRead;
    String url_string = "your URL";

    try {
        Log.d("Debug", "Start Uploading");
        FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(
                exiting_file_path);
        URL url = new URL(url_string);
        httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        httpUrlConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpUrlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpUrlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("content-type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

        dos = new DataOutputStream(httpUrlConn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twohypens + boundary + lineend);
        dos.writeBytes("content-disposition:form-data; name=\"upload_file\"; filename=\""
                + exiting_file_path + "\"" + lineend);
        dos.writeBytes(lineend);

        int buferAvailable = fileInStream.available();
        buferSize = Math.min(buferAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[buferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInStream.read(buffer, 0, buferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, buferSize);
            buferAvailable = fileInStream.available();
            buferSize = Math.min(buferAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInStream.read(buffer, 0, buferSize);
        }
        dos.writeBytes(lineend);
        dos.writeBytes(twohypens + boundary + twohypens + lineend);
        fileInStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, 1).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, 1).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + e, 1).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(
                httpUrlConn.getInputStream());

        while ((STRRRR = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("Debug", "Server Response " + STRRRR);
        }
        inStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return STRRRR;
}
```

Comment: it is just String. for get response from server. it show you detail file uploaded or not. one more thing you use PHP web services?

Answer (score 0):

You most probably did something funny with URL, like specifying it as "http://example.com" and server immediately redirects you to "http://example.com/" (note the slash on the end) with redirect code 302.

Check the headers returned by the server, it usually contains the correct location.

Comment: how to i check this? Check the headers returned by the server, it usually contains the correct location.